# index.php controller checks on path instead of action parameter

Tags: php

In my index.php, I control which template to require according to the action parameter.

```
$action = isset( $_GET['action'] ) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
```

In my other page, I assign the action in the href.

```
<a href=".?action=post&amp;postId=<?php echo $post->id?>">
```

When you hover the link, it will show you something like

```
...?action=post&postId=101
```

But I don't want to show it like that.  Instead, I want to show it like

```
.../post/101
```

And in the href, I kinda use

```
<a href="./post/<?php echo $post->id?>">
```

My question is, how will then I be able to handle it in the index.php

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained?rq=1) can help

Comment: so does this mean that i can keep my implementation of index.php and just update the .htaccess file?

Comment: yes you can keep your implementation

Comment: thank you, will try that

Comment: look @ `Josh S.`'s answer

Answer (score 1):

Use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)\/?$  /page-to-load.php?action=post&postId=$1 [NC,PT,L]
```

With this example the server will take

**www.example.com/article/101**

and redirect it to **www.example.com/page-to-load.php?action=post&postId=101**

while retaining **www.example.com/article/101** in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. Let's limit it to one method per answer: I pick PATH_INFO.

You can read up on the description of PATH_INFO in the cgi specification at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.5

Basically the webserver, after deciding which resource to serve/which script to run, makes the additional path available through a variable called PATH_INFO. In PHP this usually ends up in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

But you have to configure the webserver to accept and propagate this information.
For the httpd apache this is done by setting [AcceptPathInfo On](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo).

For other webservers [it](http://kbeezie.com/php-self-path-nginx/) is [done](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis) differently.